# Can Google Chrome run on ARM architecture?

Tags: chrome

I am running Debian on an ARM device, is there any build of Google Chrome for that?

Comment: You can [build Chromium by yourself](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/linux_chromium_arm.md). I don't know if Chrome is available for arm-linux.

Comment: Compiling Chromium from source sounds a little bit out of my noob comfort zone, but thanks for the advice anyway. I think I will just stay with Midori and Dillon. They should run better anyway on my limited hardware. Anyway, if you make an answer mentioning that there is no ARM build but it is possible to compile it, I will accept and upvote.

Comment: What ARM device???

Comment: @Fiksdal compiling a package from source is really no work at all, just grab the source and `cd` to the directory, then `./configure`, `sudo make` and `sudo make install`. Or, you could trick `gcc` into thinking you're building on ARM64, and pass such a compiler flag.

Comment: @cat I see. But even those instructions don't tell me enough. I'm. not sure if you understand what level of noob you are dealing with here. It's OK, I'm fine with Dillon and Midori.

Comment: @wb9688 A Samsung I9305 running a Debian-like compatability layer.

Comment: Do you have a Linux desktop PC that you can plug your tablet into and transfer files?

Comment: I have a Linux Mint live CD and a Debian-based bootable USB. My laptop is a Hackintosh running OS X 10.10.1.

Comment: @Gilles If you want, you can answer with a tutorial on building Chromium from source because I'm not gonna write one 'til tomorrow

Comment: Two things about Chromium, @Fiksdal: First, chromium is a huge multiheaded process and I imagine you'd need a fairly beefy tablet to have the desktop version run latency free; second, not only will you likely not have easy access to your Chrome Apps (as they are a Google thing), but it will be a pain to install things like flash and friends to allow you to watch Netflix (and possibly even some youtube videos) on Chromium because it is open-source and closed source things are not open source. For these reasons, unless you *really* love Chromium (*not* Google Chrome), I would stick with Firefox.

Comment: What about installing through apt-get? `apt-get install chromium` - http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-do-i-install-google-chrome

Comment: @nwildner That gives "Package 'chromium' has no installation candidate." Some people were describing the same thing in the thread you linked to.

Comment: Well. I dont know what arm microarchitecture you are dealing with it, but these instructions could be helpful - http://conoroneill.net/running-the-latest-chromium-45-on-debian-jessie-on-your-raspberry-pi-2/

Comment: @nwildner Almost worked! Chromium even appears in my list of programs. It won't run though. Here is how it went down in Terminal: https://goo.gl/kv9Ysi Btw, I did install the library and codecs first as instructed in the link you gave.

Comment: Anyway, Dillo and Midori are best on this basic hardware of mine anyways :)

Comment: @Fiksdal. How about if you run `apt-get -f install` to fix all the remaining non-resolved dependency issues? Cheers :)

Comment: @nwildner Tried it now, Terminal still told me that the package has no installation candidate.

Comment: I requested this in *2016*: https://crbug.com/677140

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google only releases Chrome for Linux on amd64. There are also arm packages, but they're for Android and iOS, not Linux.

Chromium, which is Chrome minus a few features, is available on any platform where you manage to build it. That's not an easy task, but these days, several Linux distributions have Chromium packages for arm, including [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=chromium) (armhf and arm64, i.e. 32-bit ARM with floating point and 64-bit ARM).

Comment: This is still true in October 2021. The information about Google Chrome ARM build you might find when searching for this topic only refers to the build for MacOS with M1 processor. There is no Google Chrome compiled for ARM Linux.